# pyspark agg without outliers for each columns

Tags: pyspark, multiple-columns, aggregate-functions, outliers

I am facing a problem that use `agg` function to calculate statistics without outliers for multiple columns.
I need to remove 25 percentile and 75 percentile for "each column" and calculate min, max, mean.

The input table:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 1, 1, 1),
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 2, 12, 22),
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 3, 13, 23),
        ('a', 'E1', 'C1', 4, 133, 123),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 1, 1, 2),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 2, 15, 25),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 3, 56, 126),
        ('b', 'E1', 'C1', 4, 156, 126),
    ],
    schema=['sheet', 'equipment', 'chamber', 'time', 'value1', 'value2']
)

df.printSchema()
df.show(10, False)

+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+
|sheet|equipment|chamber|time|value1|value2|
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+
|a    |E1       |C1     |1   |1     |1     |
|a    |E1       |C1     |2   |12    |22    |
|a    |E1       |C1     |3   |13    |23    |
|a    |E1       |C1     |4   |133   |123   |
|b    |E1       |C1     |1   |1     |2     |
|b    |E1       |C1     |2   |15    |25    |
|b    |E1       |C1     |3   |16    |26   |
|b    |E1       |C1     |4   |156   |126   |
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+
```

The expected result:

| sheet | equipment | chamber | value1_min | value1_max | value1_mean | value2_min | value2_max | value2_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | E1 | C1 | 12 | 13 | 12.5 | 22 | 23 | 23.5 |
| b | E1 | C1 | 15 | 16 | 15.5 | 25 | 26 | 25.5 |

Here is  my code so far,

but it takes `number of columns` times for loops, is there more efficient expression for this problem?

```
    groupby_list = ["sheet_id"]
    dummy_origin = df.select(groupby_list).dropDuplicates(groupby_list)
    w = W.Window.partitionBy(groupby_list)

    param_df = df.drop(*groupby_list,'equipment', 'chamber','time')
    
    for col_name in param_df.columns:
        # for each column compute statistics and then join
        
        aggregation = [func.mean(col_name).alias(f"{col_name}_mean"), 
                           func.stddev(col_name).alias(f"{col_name}_std"),
                           func.min(col_name).alias(f"{col_name}_min"),
                           func.max(col_name).alias(f"{col_name}_max")
                          ]   
        df_25_75 = (df.select('sheet_id',col_name)
         .withColumn("p25",func.percentile_approx(func.col(col_name), 0.25).over(w))
         .withColumn("p75",func.percentile_approx(func.col(col_name), 0.75).over(w))
         .withColumn("in_range", func.when( ((func.col(col_name) <= func.col('p75')) & (func.col(col_name) >= func.col('p25'))),1).otherwise(0))
         .where(func.col('in_range') == 1)
         .groupby(*groupby_list).agg(*aggregation)
                    )
        dummy_origin= dummy_origin.join(df_25_75,['sheet_id'],'inner')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Jonathan's logic, we can shorten the code a little by using structs for the percentiles. note that [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark-sql-functions-percentile-approx) accepts a list of percentages as well and, if passed, it will generate the percentiles as an array *where the N<sup>th</sup> element in the resulting array is for the N<sup>th</sup> element in the passed list of percentages*.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

value_fields = ['value1', 'value2']

# just thinking ahead for the condition to be used in every column
column_condition = lambda c: func.col(c).between(func.col('valcol_pers.'+c+'_per')[0], func.col('valcol_pers.'+c+'_per')[1])

# calculate the 0.25 & 0.75 percentiles and store in a struct - `valcol_pers`
# where the struct field names will indicate the column the percentiles refer to
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('valcol_pers', 
               func.struct(*[func.percentile_approx(c, [0.25, 0.75]).over(wd.partitionBy('sheet')).alias(c+'_per') for c in value_fields])
               ). \
    groupBy('sheet', 'equipment', 'chamber'). \
    agg(*[func.min(func.when(column_condition(c), func.col(c))).alias(c+'_min') for c in value_fields],
        *[func.max(func.when(column_condition(c), func.col(c))).alias(c+'_max') for c in value_fields],
        *[func.mean(func.when(column_condition(c), func.col(c))).alias(c+'_mean') for c in value_fields],
        *[func.stddev(func.when(column_condition(c), func.col(c))).alias(c+'_stddev') for c in value_fields]
        ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+---------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
# |sheet|equipment|chamber|value1_min|value2_min|value1_max|value2_max|value1_mean      |value2_mean       |value1_stddev     |value2_stddev     |
# +-----+---------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
# |b    |E1       |C1     |1         |2         |56        |126       |24.0             |69.75             |28.583211855912904|65.62710314090259 |
# |a    |E1       |C1     |1         |1         |13        |23        |8.666666666666666|15.333333333333334|6.658328118479393 |12.423096769056148|
# +-----+---------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

---

the `valcol_pers` field would look like the following

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('valcol_pers', 
               func.struct(*[func.percentile_approx(c, [0.25, 0.75]).over(wd.partitionBy('sheet')).alias(c+'_per') for c in value_fields])
               )
```

```
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+-------------------+
|sheet|equipment|chamber|time|value1|value2|valcol_pers        |
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+-------------------+
|b    |E1       |C1     |1   |1     |2     |{[1, 56], [2, 126]}|
|b    |E1       |C1     |2   |15    |25    |{[1, 56], [2, 126]}|
|b    |E1       |C1     |3   |56    |126   |{[1, 56], [2, 126]}|
|b    |E1       |C1     |4   |156   |126   |{[1, 56], [2, 126]}|
|a    |E1       |C1     |1   |1     |1     |{[1, 13], [1, 23]} |
|a    |E1       |C1     |2   |12    |22    |{[1, 13], [1, 23]} |
|a    |E1       |C1     |3   |13    |23    |{[1, 13], [1, 23]} |
|a    |E1       |C1     |4   |133   |123   |{[1, 13], [1, 23]} |
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+-------------------+

root
 |-- sheet: string (nullable = true)
 |-- equipment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- chamber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- valcol_pers: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value1_per: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = false)
 |    |-- value2_per: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just re-write your code and I think it still have room to improve. I'm not sure if joining with looping in your case is a necessity.

First find the p25 and p75 of each value:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('sheet', 'equipment', 'chamber')

df2 = df\
    .select(
        '*',
        *[
            func.percentile_approx(func.col(col), 0.25).over(w).alias(f"{col}_p25") for col in df.columns[-2:]
        ],
        *[
            func.percentile_approx(func.col(col), 0.75).over(w).alias(f"{col}_p75") for col in df.columns[-2:]
        ]
    )

df2.show(10, False)
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|sheet|equipment|chamber|time|value1|value2|value1_p25|value2_p25|value1_p75|value2_p75|
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|a    |E1       |C1     |1   |1     |1     |1         |1         |13        |23        |
|a    |E1       |C1     |2   |12    |22    |1         |1         |13        |23        |
|a    |E1       |C1     |3   |13    |23    |1         |1         |13        |23        |
|a    |E1       |C1     |4   |133   |123   |1         |1         |13        |23        |
|b    |E1       |C1     |1   |1     |2     |1         |2         |56        |126       |
|b    |E1       |C1     |2   |15    |25    |1         |2         |56        |126       |
|b    |E1       |C1     |3   |56    |126   |1         |2         |56        |126       |
|b    |E1       |C1     |4   |156   |126   |1         |2         |56        |126       |
+-----+---------+-------+----+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Then just use a list to collect the calculation. The only thing that I modify here is just the `func.lit(None)` for the calculation because we don't want the outlier to affect the result:

```
aggregation = []
for col in df.columns[-2:]:
    aggregation += [
        func.avg(func.when((func.col(col)>=func.col(f"{col}_p25"))&(func.col(col)<=func.col(f"{col}_p75")), func.col(col)).otherwise(func.lit(None))).alias(f"{col}_mean"),
        func.stddev(func.when((func.col(col)>=func.col(f"{col}_p25"))&(func.col(col)<=func.col(f"{col}_p75")), func.col(col)).otherwise(func.lit(None))).alias(f"{col}_std"),
        func.min(func.when((func.col(col)>=func.col(f"{col}_p25"))&(func.col(col)<=func.col(f"{col}_p75")), func.col(col)).otherwise(func.lit(None))).alias(f"{col}_min"),
        func.max(func.when((func.col(col)>=func.col(f"{col}_p25"))&(func.col(col)<=func.col(f"{col}_p75")), func.col(col)).otherwise(func.lit(None))).alias(f"{col}_max"),
    ]

df3 = df2\
    .groupBy('sheet', 'equipment', 'chamber')\
    .agg(*aggregation)
df3.show(10, False)
+-----+---------+-------+-----------------+------------------+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
|sheet|equipment|chamber|value1_mean      |value1_std        |value1_min|value1_max|value2_mean       |value2_std        |value2_min|value2_max|
+-----+---------+-------+-----------------+------------------+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
|a    |E1       |C1     |8.666666666666666|6.658328118479393 |1         |13        |15.333333333333334|12.423096769056148|1         |23        |
|b    |E1       |C1     |24.0             |28.583211855912904|1         |56        |69.75             |65.62710314090259 |2         |126       |
+-----+---------+-------+-----------------+------------------+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
```

But I doubt that if you use `percentile_approx`, could you achieve your expected output (For example, sheet-a equipment-E1 chamber-C1 value of `p25` and `p75` is 1 and 13 respectively)? Since `percentile_approx` is just a proximate calculation, when you check my `df2`, it seems that the p25 and p75 value are not your expected one.